# Downloading Steam OS Source

Tags: download, operating-system, steam

Like a lot of you guys out there, I'm pretty pumped for Steam OS. I have a link to the source code, which I want to download:

http://repo.steampowered.com/steamos/

Is there an easy way for me to download all of these files?

There's no download button, and right clicking doesn't give me anything useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `wget` to recursively download the directories you want.

`wget -r --include-directories=steamos/ --directory-prefix=steamos/ --wait=15--reject=index.htm* "http://repo.steampowered.com/steamos/"`

- `-r` tells `wget` that we want to recursively download the given site.
- `--include-directories=steamos/` limits our download to just the steamos folder, from the root of the site. Otherwise it would try to download absolutely everything from http://repo.steampowered.com/
- `--directory-prefix=steamos/` specifies the folder this will be place in once its downloaded. By default, the download will be placed in 'repo.steampowered.com/steamos/'.
- `--reject=index.htm*` junks the three index pages that would otherwise be saved to each sub-directory.
- `--wait=15` places a delay of 15 seconds between your downloads, for the sake of being kind to the servers.

My main reference for this was http://learningbitsandbytes.blogspot.ca/2013/07/downloading-source-code-from-svngit.html

Comment: Great answer, thorough and well explained. I made a slight change, I took off the 15 second delay, it was taking too long, and I didn't get banned from the server, so it doesnt seem that they mind the constant pinging.

Comment: Nice answer, I +1 the answer for the --wait=15